# How to use :not() selector inclusive of parent:first-child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery function that makes the tr element a hyperlink, however, it should not trigger when clicking on any child elements beyond the td. Also I would like to exclude the first td element because it contains a checkbox.

I tried this but it doesn't allow anything to work like checkboxes, child links and child javascript:

```
$('table.table-striped tr[data-href] td').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    window.location = $parent.data('href');
}).children().click(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Then I tried this and it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
$(this).on('click', 'table.table-striped tr[data-href] td:not(:first-child):not(a.codelink):not(.actions):not(.dropdown-toggle):not(.dropdown):not(.caret):not(input)', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    window.location = $parent.data('href');
});
```

Here is an example of the table row:

```
<tr class="datarow" data-href="/stock/675144">
    <td><span class="largercheckbox"><input type="checkbox" class="selectrow" id="chk675144" data-id="675144"></span></td>
    <td><div class="stockindentifier">test</div></td>
    <td><a href="/link" class="codelink grey">1011.3</a></td>
    <td class="actions">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#"><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><li><a href="/stock/edit/675144"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a></li><li><a href="/stock/delete/675144" data-confirm="true" rel="nofollow"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li></ul>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: `:not()` only works on the element it’s applied to, so `td:not(input)` makes little sense. You’ll want to look into event delegation, where you capture all clicks on the `td` and filter using `$(e.target).is(‘td’)` or something similar.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you, my final working solution with your help is below.

Comment: It would have worked as expected if you used an extra space between the ":not-selectors", like:

'table.table-striped tr[data-href] td:not(:first-child) :not(a.codelink) :not(.actions)...' and so on. Since the classes are not inside the td tag-element itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using is() to ensure it is the td element clicked prevents the action from running on any child elements:

```
$('table.table-striped tr[data-href] td').click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('td'))
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');
        window.location = $parent.data('href');
    }
});
```